# Devise controller for models with polymorphic relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, polymorphism

tl;dr:

the Devise::RegistrationsController doesn't instantiate associated polymorphic models, what's the best way to solve that?

setup:

I have an address model which I am associating with different entities (e.g. a person, a business) and thus am using a polymorphic relationship:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :address, :as => :addressable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :address # to make fields_for work
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

I have used the Person model as the Devise model but run into issues where the Address object is not instantiated or saved when signing up for a new account.

The Person controller, which to my knowledge is replaced by the Devise RegistrationController (routing: `new_person_registration GET    /person/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new`) had code to instantiate the respective objects which used to do the trick before I started using Devise:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
    [...]
    def create
        @person = Person.new(params[:person])
        @person.address = Address.new(params[:address])
        [...some checking...]
        @person.save
        @person.address.save

    end
    def new
        @person = Person.new
        @person.address = Address.new
    end

end
```

Now it seems that the Devise::RegistrationsController doesn't create the Address object.

One suggested resolution was to use callbacks to initialize the objects, thus my person model has:

```
before_create :instantiate_all
before_save :save_all

def save_all
    self.address.save
    self.save 
end

def instantiate_all
    if self.address.nil?
        self.address = Address.new
    end
end
```

With that I still get

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `address' for nil:NilClass):
    app/models/person.rb:25:in `save_all'
```

I was looking into overriding the RegistrationController but it seems that by calling `super` I will get the whole block of the respective parent method executed and thus won't be able to insert my desired action.

Lastly, overriding the controller, copying its code and adding my code just seems too wrong to be the only way to get this done.

I'd appreciate your guys' thoughts on that.